# REGEXP within IF ELSE giving syntax error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a simple REGEXP check within an IF condition, but i get a syntax error in MySql 5.6.17 monitor. what am i doing wrong?

```
IF SELECT '123' REGEXP '[0-9]+'
THEN SELECT 1;
ELSE SELECT 2;
END IF;
```

Comment: show your complete sql also add details what you are trying to achieve

Comment: That is my complete SQL. My intention is to check if a parameter (hardcoded as '123' in the question) is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `CASE`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN '123' REGEXP '[0-9]+'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 2
       END 
FROM...
```

Comment: Bingo! i still wonder what's wrong with the syntax in my If statement.

Comment: the `if` statement you've used works inside a procedure.